# How to install and run inetd on OSX or the equivalent in launchd

Tags: osx, inetd

I'm trying to capture the data destined for a "networked printer" so it can be processed locally or forwarded to another system. It looks like [Linux as a network printer device (Raw, port 9100)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203173/linux-as-a-network-printer-device-raw-port-9100)
will do what I want and only requires:
`9100 stream tcp nowait cat > some_file`
but I'd like to be able to test it on my Macbook and that does not have `inetd`.

Potentially I could use `launchd` as it is the replacement for `inetd` on OSX, but reading the docs, it is not clear how to do the equivalent to the above. So either solution--how to get `inetd` for OSX or how to create a plist file for `launchd` do that does the equivalent is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why not just have it run persistently?

Answer (score 2):

The existing launch XML files in `/Library/LaunchDaemons` or `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` deserve study; from one of these and with some grepping about in `/etc/services`

```
$ grep 9100 /etc/services
hp-pdl-datastr  9100/udp     # PDL Data Streaming Port
hp-pdl-datastr  9100/tcp     # PDL Data Streaming Port
```

one might adapt one of the existing files to what I've saved to `/Library/LaunchDaemons/cattery.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.exampe.cattery</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/var/root/cattery</string>
    </array>
    <key>inetdCompatibility</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Wait</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
    <key>InitGroups</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Listeners</key>
        <dict>
            <key>SockServiceName</key>
            <string>hp-pdl-datastr</string>
            <key>SockType</key>
            <string>stream</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Where `/var/root/cattery` here is the bad test script (what happens if clients connect two or more times per second?):

```
$ sudo cat /var/root/cattery
#!/bin/sh
cat > "/var/root/out.$(date +%s)"
$ sudo chmod +x /var/root/cattery
```

And then we enable our new service

```
$ sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/cattery.plist
```

And feed some test data to it

```
$ echo foo | nc localhost 9100
$ sudo find /var/root -name out\* -maxdepth 1
/var/root/out.1511845970
$ sudo cat /var/root/out.1511845970
foo
$
```

NOTE this code probably should not run as `root`, a

```
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>_lp</string>
```

line as seen in `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.cups.cups-lpd.plist` may help to not run the above as `root`, in which case the output directory for data saved must be writable by that user, and the program run executable (and perhaps also readable) by that user.